# .net 6 : The difference in recording the date in the database through local and server?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I have a problem, I really don't know how to solve it.
I wrote a code that receives the solar date as a string from the input,
And through the following codes, it converts to Persian date...

query code :

```
public void AddOrEditReserveDate(ReserveDateViewModel model){       
ReserveDate reserveDate = new ReserveDate() {
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    DateReserve = model.DateReserve.Trim(),
    GeorgianDate = DateConvertor.GeorgianToShamsi(DateTime.Parse(model.DateReserve.Trim())), 
};
_context.ReserveDates.Add(reserveDate);
_context.SaveChanges();
} }
```

convert date Class :

```
 public static DateTime GeorgianToShamsi(DateTime georgian)
{
    PersianCalendar shamsiCalendar = new PersianCalendar();
    int y = shamsiCalendar.GetYear(georgian);
    int m = shamsiCalendar.GetMonth(georgian);
    int d = shamsiCalendar.GetDayOfMonth(georgian);
    return new DateTime(y, m, d, shamsiCalendar);
}
```

My main problem is that when I record the date locally in the server database, the date is recorded as Gregorian!!!

But when I record the date through the site, the date is recorded as solar?

The main problem is that Some dates are not registered in the database through the site, for example: 1402/02/30

[image: store date in database image]

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Use `datetime2` or `date` instead of `datetime` in SQL Server. The legacy `datetime` type's range is `1753-01-01` to `9999-12-31`. The "new" types introduced 18 years ago (date,datetime2, datetimeoffset) start from `0001-01-01`

Comment: A `DateTime` in .NET has no calendar either but Gregorian is implied for calculations. `PersianCalendar` allows you to make calculations and conversions using the Persian calendar *but* the `DateTime` won't know where those values came from.

Comment: SQL Server's date ranges are specified in [Date and Time Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#DateandTimeDataTypes)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i used this property `public DateTime GeorgianDate { get; set; }`

and made with datetime2 format

Comment: The error is due to the conversion of a string date to a DateTime.  Looks like some dates were loaded incorrectly into the table.  Error looks like Mode is wrong : GeorgianDate = DateConvertor.GeorgianToShamsi(DateTime.Parse(model.DateReserve.Trim())),

Comment: @jdweng When I remove the date change method, the same problem occurs again, that is, the date is recorded in the server as a solar system

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How can I create a date format property in .net6?

Comment: What is the input string you are getting?  Are all dates using same code? It looks like the DateReserve looks consistent but not the matching GeorgianDate.

Comment: @jdweng `1402/02/30` like this ... i used `parseexact` but has error

Comment: What is differences between first 2 rows of table and last when dates were entered?

Comment: @jdweng Gregorian dates are recorded from local, but solar dates are the same from the code server

Comment: I think your code is going in the wrong direction.  Your code is taking a Georgian Date and  converting to Shamsi (GeorgianToShamsi(DateTime georgian)) but you are starting with a Shamsi string.

Comment: @jdweng You are right, but when I remove the convert code, the Georgian date is not registered on the server

Comment: The function should be ShamsToGeorgiani(string Shams)